# How to pass parameters from google composer to dataflow template

Tags: airflow, dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to pass parameter from google composer into a dataflow template as following way, but it does not work.

```
# composer code
trigger_dataflow = DataflowTemplateOperator(
     task_id="trigger_dataflow",
     template="gs://mybucket/my_template",
     dag=dag,
     job_name='appsflyer_events_daily',
     parameters={
         "input": f'gs://my_bucket/' + "{{ ds }}" + "/*.gz"
     }
)

# template code
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
@classmethod
def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--input',
        default='gs://my_bucket/*.gz',
        help='path of input file')

def main():
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions) 
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    lines = (
        p
        | MatchFiles(user_options.input)
    )
```

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using ?

Comment: @vdolez I'm using Version : 1.10.10+composer

Comment: Also, can you provide some error logs ? Maybe the Template was not properly created, or maybe Composer misses access rights.

Comment: There are not much log @vdolez. The pipeline just doesn't match any files and finish without any error.

If I hard code the  file pattern into template, everything works OK.

Comment: Can you run the template without Composer ? From the UI for example ? Did you follow the steps [described in documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) ? Uploaded your metadata file, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moving from dataflow classic template to flex template fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like following.

```
DataflowTemplateOperator(,
         task_id="task1",
         template=get_variable_value("template"),
         on_failure_callback=update_job_message,
         parameters={
             "fileBucket": get_variable_value("file_bucket"),
             "basePath": get_variable_value("path_input"),         
             "Day": "{{ json.loads(ti.xcom_pull(key=run_id))['day'] }}",
         },
    )
```

We are using Java and in Dataflow jobs we have option class get and set like following

```
public interface MyOptions extends CommonOptions {
 
    @Description("The output bucket")
    @Validation.Required
    ValueProvider<String> getFileBucket();
    void setFileBucket(ValueProvider<String> value);
    
}
```

We need to create template for this dataflow jobs and that template will be trigger by composer dag.